# Spring Boot Environment Variable in Config does not resolve

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, environment-variables

I have the following application.properties where I have a Service definition

```
service.user=${SERVICE_USER}
service.password=${SERVICE_PASSWORD}
service.url=http://someurl.com/api
```

In the Environment I then specify User and Password

```
SERVICE_USER=test
SERVICE_PASSWORD=test
```

The configurations is read in as follows

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    private String url;

    private String user;

    private String password;

    // setters and getters
}
```

The issue is that `${SERVICE_PASSWORD}` seems not to be resolved. When checking in Debugger it's exactly the value of the variable password. Therefor I can't connect to the Service as  it gives the Error "Authentication failed". When I enter the values directly like

```
service.user=test
service.password=test
service.url=http://someurl.com/api
```

everything works as expected. Must Environment Variables, that are needed in the Code, be read in directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below configuration to read values from properties file.

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Value("${service.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${service.user}")    
    private String user;

    @Value("${service.password}")    
    private String password;
}
```

Comment: thx for your effort. after trying out your approach I realized that the Environment Variables I defined in a .env File just don't get loaded. after setting them over Spring Run Configuration in IntelliJ it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefix and do the same like this:

```
@Configuration

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")

public class ServiceConfiguration {
@Value("${url}")  
private String url;
@Value("${user}")  
private String user;
@Value("${password}")  
private String password;}
```